# Connection between two optic fiber patch panels

Tags: networking, optical-cable

The answer should be obvious but I haven't been able to confirm this.

I have two switches with 1Gb SFP LC Duplex connecting to a patch panel with two LC-SC Simplex patch cords each (I wasn't able to find Duplex patch cords in time), and the same at the other side (two switches connected to another patch panel). The question is how many drop cables do I need between the patch panels, one or four.

I have another minor point, what should be the terminations of the drop cable ? SC, or some other type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same logic applies as for any other type of patch panel. Two lines are needed for each pair of switches with a duplex SFP, making it 4 drop cables in total between the patch panels.

Also the drop cables should have SC terminations since that is the type the patch panel uses.